# HTC Sense keeps asking for Facebook permission

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, facebook, htc-one

Every time I run the Facebook app on my HTC One, HTC Sense keeps asking for permission

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Click Next and the screen disappears. Nothing seems to happen. Log out and log in again, then the same screen always appears. What is the solution for this problem? I mean, can Sense asked for permission only once?

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings>Accounts and add add your FB account to your HTC Sense app. After doing this the app shouldn't ask for the

But, as you use the native Facebook application why not entirely disable the Sense UI FB widget? The default app is more than sufficient for ones FB usage. Go to Settings>App>All and disable the default app.

Comment: I tried that. The funny thing is if you log out from the app, then you FB account entry on Settings > Accounts & Sync will also disappear. I think this behaviour is weird. My previous HTC phone was a Desire HD (running Sense 2). It didn't exhibit this behaviour.